# Parse txt file data

Tags: java, parsing, text-files, text-parsing

I've a text file which contains text as:

```
VOLT=367
CURRENT=0.07
TEMP=031
RPM=3780
63HZ
VOLT=288
CURRENT=0.00
TEMP=030
RPM=3420
57HZ
```

and so on....
I want to take this text file as input in java and create an output text file having this text arranged as:

```
367,0.07,031,3780,63
288,0.00,030,3420,57
```

and so on until the end of txt file..

Coding attempt so far:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

try {
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("file path\data.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
    BufferedWriter brw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out));
    do {
        for (int i=1;i<50;i++) {
            //I dont know what to do here
            ...
```

Comment: I'm new to java..so far I just know how to read this text file line by line using bufferedreader..but I dont know how to output dat to a text file::I'm using...

Comment: import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
try {
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("file path\data.txt");
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new
            InputStreamReader(in));
            BufferedWriter brw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out));
          
            do{  
                for(int i=1;i<50;i++){
//I dont know what to do here
}.......

Comment: Update this in your question

Comment: @newuser +1 And please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream for text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
String input = "";
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
out = new PrintWriter(outputFile);
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
while ((input = br.readLine()) != null)
{
    if(input.contains("HZ"))
    {
        result.append(input.replace("HZ", ""));
        result.append("\n");
    }
    else
    {
        result.append(input.substring(input.indexOf("=") + 1, input.length()));
        result.append(",");
    }
}
System.out.println("result : "+result.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks "newuser"..I'll try this and comeback later,hopefully to thank you again :) cheers

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple code.

```
String res="";
while ((input = br.readLine()) != null)
{
  if(input.indexOf("=")!= -1){
   res+=input.split("=+")[1]+",";
  }
  else{
    res+="\n";
  }
}
System.out.println("result : "+res.substring(0,res.length()-1));//To omit last ','
```